# How to perform PHP multiply Step By Step

Tags: php

I have one array and i want to multiply like 106 multiply by 76 but i want to multiply in this pattern it is not giving proper result

```
              1 0 6
               6 7 
      _____________
             7 4 2
           6 3 6 x 
   _________________ 
           7 1 0 2
```

The code is running properly but there is mistake in the addition i guess the output of the code is 424991   It should be 7102

```
     <?php


    $data=array(
    'digit1' => 1,
    'digit2' => 0,
    'digit3' => 6,
    'digit4' => 6,
    'digit5' => 7 );

        $a=$data['digit1']*$data['digit4'];
        $b=$data['digit2']*$data['digit4'];
        $b1=$data['digit3']*$data['digit4'];
        $c=$data['digit1']*$data['digit5'];
        $d=$data['digit2']*$data['digit5'];
        $d1=$data['digit3']*$data['digit5'];
        $e=$b+$a+$b1;
        echo $e;
        $f=$c+$d+$d1;
        echo $f;

        echo $e+$f;




?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: That's a very non-dynamic program. Change one number and it all breaks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) and [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php), you should be able to solve your problem.

Try [this updated code](https://eval.in/489948).

```
$data = array(
    'digit1' => 1,
    'digit2' => 0,
    'digit3' => 6,
    'digit4' => 6,
    'digit5' => 7
);

# ------------------------------------------------------------
$product = $data['digit5'] * $data['digit3'];
$a = $product % 10;
$carry = floor($product / 10);

$product = ($data['digit5'] * $data['digit2']) + $carry;
$b = $product % 10;
$carry = floor($product / 10);

$product = ($data['digit5'] * $data['digit1']) + $carry;
$c = $product;
#-------------------------------------------------------------
$product = $data['digit4'] * $data['digit3'];
$d = $product % 10;
$carry = floor($product / 10);

$product = ($data['digit4'] * $data['digit2']) + $carry;
$e = $product % 10;
$carry = floor($product / 10);

$product = ($data['digit4'] * $data['digit1']) + $carry;
$f = $product;
#-------------------------------------------------------------
$x = intval($c . $b . $a);
$y = intval($f . $e . $d) * 10;
#-------------------------------------------------------------

echo sprintf("%' 10d\n", $c.$b.$a);
echo sprintf("%' 9d\n", $f.$e.$d);
echo "----------\n";
echo sprintf("%' 10d\n", $x + $y);
```

You can thank me later for doing your assignment for you.

Comment: what is the logic of finding carry with floor($product/10)

Comment: @TayyabVohra It's to get the tens digit if there is one. Also, I've updated the code to display the steps.

Comment: thanks buddy 3 cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

In your program, you do not take into account the placevalues.

For example, when you multiply `$data['digit1']` by `$data['digit4']`, you should be multiplying 100 by 60, but you are instead multiplying 1 by 6.

And the reason you have a larger number (6 digits) is because you're `echo`ing two values.

This is what your program is doing (step by step):

```
$data = array(
    'digit1' => 1,
    'digit2' => 0,
    'digit3' => 6,
    'digit4' => 6,
    'digit5' => 7
);

$a=$data['digit1']*$data['digit4'];  // $a = 6
$b=$data['digit2']*$data['digit4'];  // $b = 0
$b1=$data['digit3']*$data['digit4']; // $b1 = 36
$c=$data['digit1']*$data['digit5'];  // $c = 7
$d=$data['digit2']*$data['digit5'];  // $d = 0
$d1=$data['digit3']*$data['digit5']; // $d1 = 42
$e=$b+$a+$b1;                        // $e = 42
echo $e;                             // OUTPUT 42
$f=$c+$d+$d1;                        // $f = 49
echo $f;                             // OUTPUT 42
echo $e+$f;                          // OUTPUT 91
```

This is creating your output 424991.

If you wanted to get your program to work as-is (instead of using a dynamic program like below), then the following should work:

```
$data = array(
    'digit1' => 1,
    'digit2' => 0,
    'digit3' => 6,
    'digit4' => 6,
    'digit5' => 7
);

$a=$data['digit1']*100*$data['digit4']*10;
$b=$data['digit2']*10*$data['digit4']*10;
$b1=$data['digit3']*1*$data['digit4']*10;
$c=$data['digit1']*100*$data['digit5']*1;
$d=$data['digit2']*10*$data['digit5']*1;
$d1=$data['digit3']*1*$data['digit5']*1;
$e=$b+$a+$b1;
$f=$c+$d+$d1;
echo $e+$f;
```

---

Your code is a bit too rigid, so may I suggest a more dynamic version?

Given any two numeric strings in PHP:

```
$num1 = "106";
$num2 = "67";
```

You can split each one into arrays of numbers:

```
$num1Split = str_split($num1);
$num2Split = str_split($num2);
```

And then multiply it out:

```
$total = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($num1Split); $i++)
    for($j = 0; $j < count($num2Split); $j++)
        $total += $num1Split[$i]*pow(10,count($num1Split)-$i-1) * $num2Split[$j]*pow(10,count($num2Split)-$j-1);
echo $total;
```

Comment: i have understood this problem if i multiply by ($data['digit']*10)*$data['digit4']. its even not working

Comment: it will just give the product of two numbers. I want to display both the multiplicand and the multiplier like above i have mentioned

Comment: @TayyabVohra If you just multiply digit1 by 10 it won't fix it. You have to multiply *every number by its placeholder value* (except those in the ones place).

Comment: @TayyabVohra See my annotation of your program. You're doing what I said.

Comment: no it its still not working because its not working it is giving output like 1378

Comment: @TayyabVohra Try out my code. I tested it and it works. And it uses the same logic as yours.

Comment: @TayyabVohra I adapted your code to get the right output (7102). Try it out.

Comment: Its great but how it is totaling...?

Comment: @TayyabVohra It's the same logic as yours! I just omitted the `echo`ing of the two intermediate numbers.

Comment: thanks buddy thanks very much . You make it very easier and simpler